# FileResult + redirectToAction on ERROR

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, redirect, error-handling

I have sometimes an Error when I call a webservice to get a voucher  and the webservice is KO. I need to redirect to an other Action: I need to do somethings like this:

```
  public virtual FileResult Ticket(int operationCategoryId, int orderId)
    {
        try
        {
            var orderDetail = _orderDetailBusiness.GetOrderDetail(operationCategoryId, orderId);
            byte[] ticketContent = _vpTicketMinuteBusiness.GetTicketContent(orderDetail.Parcels);
            return File(ticketContent, "application/pdf", orderId + ".pdf");
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException exception)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Error");
        }

    }
```

How Can I do this?

Comment: Does it not work if you specify the return type as ActionResult?

Comment: when i change the retuen to Action result, I dont receive the file

Comment: That's really strange as they're interchangeable

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 return new FileStreamResult(ms, "application/ms-excel")
            {
                FileDownloadName = "yourfile.xlsx",
            };
```